# fire javascript function from asp.net codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, server-side

This is my javascript function ,

```
 function returnToParent() {            
        var oArg = new Object();
        var oWnd = GetRadWindow();
        oArg.ReturnValue = "Submit";
        oWnd.close(oArg);
    }
```

And this is how I call this function on client side

```
 <button title="Submit" runat="server" id="close" onclick="returnToParent(); return false;">
                    OK</button>
```

I want to fire this function in server side button click event .
What I've done is add new button

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="rtxtSubmitChange" OnClick="rtxtSubmitChange_Click"  Text="Submit" />
```

and in ButtonClick Event ,

```
protected void rtxtSubmitChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),
"MyKey",
"returnToParent();",
false);
    }
```

But It doesn't work . What I am wrong in my code ?

Comment: I'm surprised you managed to compile this. `OnClick` is to be handled on the server side (C#), and `OnClientClick` on the client (Javascript). So, besides fixing your markup, you should call the Javascript function from the server side just if there's something you need to do before doing so. Otherwise, just use the `OnClientClick`.

Comment: Please check if javascript file containing function is available. If so check if function is available or not. Sometimes js files are cached & new functions definitions thus are not available

Comment: @MelanciaUK , actually I don't need to use client side . I've to make some CUD function in server side and then to fire this javascript function . Thanks ! Any advice ?

Comment: Then you should have `OnClick="rtxtSubmitChange_Click"`.

Comment: @Pranav , Yes , firing this javascript from client side is OK .

Comment: OH , sorry @MelanciaUK , my bad . I have two button ! The button in my question is just for testing client side . I have another `rtxtSubmitChange` button that has `rtxtSubmitChange_Click` event :) Thank you !

Comment: Please edit your question to show all the relevant code.

Comment: I've edited my question Friends ! Guide me please :) What I am wrong ?

Comment: `Page.ClientScript` is deprecated. Use `ClientScriptManager` instead. But if you're playing with `UpdatePanels`, use `ScriptManager` instead. Also, when you stick a breakpoint on the click handler, does it get hit?

Comment: No , It doesn't hit !

Comment: Then your problem is not related to calling a client script from the code behind. Your problem actually is that your button is not even firing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), this.ClientID, "returnToParent()", true);
```

OR

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), this.ClientID, "returnToParent()", true);
```

For more details refer :[ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)